# Connect MySql database from spring in a runntime

Tags: mysql, spring

First of all I must say that I'm Spring Newbie and trying to figure out how stuff works. As a training project I'm trying to build web app (Mysql,spring,thymeleaf,bootstrap,jquery). For now goes very well except the part with db connection...

Database: Someone with "Administrator" role can add/register other users (for example user with "Teacher" role or "Cook" role) trough stored procedure. Each user have username, password and role (and some other not important private data). After registration deppending on a role, each user gets permissions to do something on a database.

I want to configure my app so that when user logs in, app will establish database connection with his own data (username and pass).

So far I can make db connection with single user (application.properties)...

Can anyone pleas help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best practice for DB connections is to have a connection pool which is instantiated during Spring Context initialization. By passing the credentials dynamically, you will need to do your own connection management which is an overhead.

What's the reason for that approach (creating connections with credentials at run time)?

Comment: I have no special reason except learning and discovering. Just want to try it out.